# No ruler icon in Font-Awesome

Tags: css, font-awesome

I'm using Font-Awesome in my project and I need a ruler icon, at the moment I created a button with `background-image` a ruler icon but it doesn't change the color if it's hover.

How can I add the same functions of Font-Awesome at this button?

I need to make it responsive, the color of `button` `button:hover` will be different for every client, so I can't create 200 icons.

With font-awesome I simply use `css` `color` to change the color of the icon

Here a screenshot of how it looks now, the print is the `hover` color

[image]

here the code I use:

```
<button type="button" class="custbtn"><em class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true"></em></button>
<button type="button" class="custbtn"><em class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></em></button>
<button class="custbtn" id="tlruler" value="off"></button>

.custbtn {
    background: #0b3c5d;
    color: #fff;
}
.custbtn:hover {
   background: #328cc1;
   color: #d9b310;
}

#tlruler {
  background-image: url("../images/ruler.png");
  background-size: 20px 20px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}
```

With Font-Awesome you can use `css color` to change the icon color

Comment: A working code example would help more than a screenshot :-|

Comment: I don't have it, I can copy the code in the question or try to create a codePen

Comment: If FA don't provide a "ruler" icon, you can't do this. Perhaps file a request with them?

Comment: it's an open request since 2013 :( Maybe there is a way I can hack the code or use part of it to do what I need

Comment: Nope....you're trying to change the color a background-image with CSS and **you can't do that**.

Comment: You might be able to create your own icon font (icomoon) and use that though for this specific button. Complicated though.

Comment: why the down vote??? I understand I can't do it with CSS, I''m asking for a way to have the same result as FA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FontAwesome icons aren't images. They are *fonts*, and that's why they respond to CSS `color` attribute changes.

To get a similar effect, you'd need a ruler icon from another library that provides such font-icons. I generally go to [FlatIcon](https://www.flaticon.com/search?word=ruler) when FontAwesome doesn't have a particular icon. From there you could download the icons as fonts.

The steps for FlatIcon.com would be:

1. Add the selected icons to a collection.
2. Download the collection in IconFont format. This will download a zip file containing a CSS file and another set of font files (applicable to different browsers).
3. Now you could simply refer to this CSS file in your HTML page, and create icons by adding particular classes to elements:

   ```
   <span class="flaticon-ruler"></span>
   ```

   You could also color these icons with CSS styles:

   ```
   <span class="flaticon-ruler" style="color: red;"></span>
   ```
4. **[Optional]** Move the CSS rules from the downloaded CSS file to your own CSS file. This is merely to avoid making one extra round-trip from the browser.

Comment: I have an SVG file, but how can I change the color on hover? I know how to do it if I use an inline SVG in HTML but in a button? I open the SVG with a text editor, copy the SVG in the button and use CSS to achieve the result?

Comment: @Sebastiano I stand corrected. Instead of SVG file, you would need to add the fonts to a collection, and when you download the collection, select the option to download IconFont. It will come with a CSS file. I will update my answer with some more details.